Solana-keygen create new pubkey when it freezes
I am trying to generate a new pubkey.
Every time I run:
solana-keygen pubkey

I get:
Error: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)

I have tried to generate a new pubkey with:
solana-keygen new --force

but it just crashes every time I do that.
How can I fix that? I've set my config file to
 C:\Users\Admin\.config\solana\cli\config.yml

and verified it is there
